# notification in .net entityframework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement to send some notification to the users logged in.
My application uses windows credentials and will login to the application with that.
Once login he should be able to see the notification if any added by admin/some1 of the website
something like we have in facebook. I am using MVC 4 and entityframework.
Anyone have idea about how to implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking into a pub/sub framework like [Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/RedisPubSub).

You can also look into some of the more powerful frameworks, like [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr). SignalR was designed with this in mind. It's capable of [pushing messages to the client](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR), and even returning them back to the server (if needed) in real-time. It's built on top of the same general frameworks that WebAPI and MVC are.

Comment: Can you suggest me a sample application for reference

Comment: [Here is a tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr). It walks you through a real world application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929096/signal-r-notification Can you please check this

Comment: Marking as answered because the link gives a sample application